# How to solve "slider's all images display "in Angularjs But in HTML slider works properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angularjs

When I am using HTML, then image slider works properly but when I am using AngularJS then my image slider displays all image. After display all images when I clicking next button then my slider work properly. I was checking slider length then it shows me one slider but I have 4 images, and when I click the next button then it shows 4 slider length. Please help me!!! thanks in advance

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container" ng-init="image()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="img in images">
      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">{{img.id}}</div>
        <img class="size-i" ng-src="{{img.oe_images}}" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a class="prev" style="font-size:36px;" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" style="font-size:36px;" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
        <div class="row paddi">
          <div class="column" ng-repeat="img in images">
            <img class="demo cursor border-demo" ng-src="{{img.oe_images}}" style="width:100%;" data="{{img.id}}" ng-click="currentSlide(img.id)" alt="{{img.oe_images}}">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
//Javascript code for image slider
<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);

  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    console.log(n);
    var i;

    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");

    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    console.log(slides.length);
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
</script>
//Controller.js file 'use strict'; var app = angular.module('myApp', []); app.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope,$http) { $scope.image = function(){ $http.get(baseURL+'pptAllImages').then(successCallback, errorCallback); function successCallback(response){
$scope.images=response.data; console.log($scope.images); } function errorCallback(error){ console.log(error); } }; });
```

[In the picture showing all images display after click next button it works properly][1]
        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zz7k.png

Everything is good in HTML code but this problem comes when I am using AngularJS. I am using automatic slider then it's work properly in AngularJS but I want to onclick slider. I also used other onclick slider but in every onclick slider comes same problem. All data I am fetching from database but problem comes only in AngularJS. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to move the javascript functions into the controller and bind them to the scope.

```
$scope.showSlides(){}
```

Also make sure you bootstrap the app with

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

Example of working angular image slider...
http://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/t8BaZ/

Comment: please explain me how i will use $scope.showSlides(){} this function. when i am using it shows me it's not defined